# Is this a correct way to pass props from child to parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

Many times, when I want to apply proper encapsulation, i.e storing form input fields data at a form component and later sending the data via an ajax call in my main component where I store the main state of the application instead of storing everything on a single component, I encounter this dilemma: Either write it all in a single component (form and ajax call), or split the work to different encapsulated components while transferring the state / props via a function callback. hence my question - is this a "correct" way to move the props up to the parent component? (In this example, just to keep it simple - logging the data from the child component via the parent component)
If not, what would be a better way?
Thanks in advance!

```
function Parent() {
  function getChildData(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  return <Child childData={getChildData} />;
}

function Child(props) {
  return <button onClick={sendChildData}>Update Parent's State!</button>;

  function sendChildData() {
    let data = "Data from child component!";
    props.childData(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Parent.jsx**

```
const [childData, setChildData] = useState(null);

const Parent = () => {
  const handleData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    setChildData(data);
  }
  return <Child onHandleData={handleData} />;
}
```

**Child.jsx**

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const { onHandleData } = props;

  return <button onClick={onHandleData("Data from child component!")}>Update Parent's State!</button>;
}
```

Comment: you can't use a hook `useState` outside a functional component, second and you are invoking the function on `onClick`. given your solution it should be `onClick={() => onHandleData("Data from child component!" }`